spacemacs configuration for react (MERN)
How do I set spacemacs for programming in react js (MERN)? I enabled all possible layereas, but I get a constant error: "LSP : : Error on the language server side: Request initialize failed with message: Can't find typescript.js or tsserverlibrary.js in "" (Internal Error)". I have installed typescript and in bash it finds the path to typescript. I use Linux Mint Cinnamon.
I tried to write the path manually to the typescript install location in .spacemacs, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't autocomplete my js or jsx files, but it works in the .spacemacs file. I would be very grateful with a concrete example of a .spacemacs setup file.

It works finnaly. I reinstalled all dependncies and libaryes and works.
